# Does anyone recognize the aircraft in this photo?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I saw this aircraft flying in the vicinity of Dulles International Airport today, while I was inside my car. I could not tell whether or not it was a turbine engine as I could not hear it.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks just like a De Havilland Dash 8 of some sort, likely a Q 400.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was driving me crazy. I believe you nailed it, though. We don't see many turbo-prop airliners around here near Dulles.  Usually just an occasional King Air or similar executive sized bird. The rest are mostly Boeing, Airbus and Bombardier jet-liners.